# Entity model is creating a second designer file on each build, why

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

EF v5.0, database first model.  Code Generation Strategy = Default.

For some odd reason each time I build my project the model is creating a second Model1.designer.vb file (the new one being named Model11.Designer.vb).  Obviously I have done something stupid but am at a loss as to what.  Has this happened to anyone else before and if so did they establish what the cause was.

To the best of my recollection this started following a warning message along the lines of 'This file has been altered outside of the designer window.  Do you want to save the changes'.

I'd welcome any suggestions as to what I may have done to cause this behaviour and rectify it.

Answer (score 0):

in your project file you can check the  name of the Designer file it will generate, check that and change it if needed.

some times when you delete and recreate the model, still there can be old designer file in the source folder. since old file exist next time it will generate `Model11.Designer.vb`.

Comment: Hi Damith.  Thanks for your reply, where exactly would I find that particular property.  I've had a good look but with no joy as yet.